# How to export POSTMAN tests to java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, postman

I can click on CODE in postman to convert, for example, GET request to java.
But how can I convert the test to java? For example, validation if it returns code 200:

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

Thank you!